# Reset current NavigationController and present another tab

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app (with a UITabBarController) that can reach the final payment view via two tabs, each with their own NavigationController.
(The illustration only shows the two tabs in question)

When payment is successful I want to reset both NavigationControllers and present tab 1.

If I was on tab 1 I could just use this code:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

But if I was on tab 2 that only brings me to the first viewController in navigationController in tab 2...

How can I present another tab while also resetting the NavigationController I am on (and others)?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a custom `UITabBarController` or make a category that has a method called something like: `completePayment()`

```
- (void) completePayment
{
   [self setSelectedIndex:n] // n is the index of your destination tab
   [[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:m] popToRootViewControllerAnimated: YES]; // reset the stack in the current tab
}
```

2) trigger this method from the ViewController that the paymant is done as such:`[self.tabbarController completePayment];`

3) Profit!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably ways of doing this in somewhat hacky ways, but what I will suggest you is that you reconsider your flow when you ask yourself a question like this one. Each UITab is designed to hold a `UINavigationView` that is self contained and independent from other UITab elements. If you force reset a tab that you are not on, you are breaking the flow and confusing the users.

So I recommend you push your Payment ViewController, wherever you need it in the app. And don't mess with other Tabs states.

Comment: Hmm, well let me put it differently, if the user succeeded in payment via tab 2 , then I want to reset that navbarcontroller, and show the user his "Pending orders" which is on another tab..  How do I reset my current navigationController (the one belonging to tab 2) and then present another tab (say tab 1)?

Comment: You dont jump tabs programatically. It should be %100 users control. Thats what its designed for. But if you must, I guess you can call popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true) on your current tab and once its finished navigate to the other tab like : self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = n; Afterall you have an acess to your UITabBarController from anywhere in the navigation.

Comment: Hmm, well that would like be very hacky and user would notice a "double unwind".  Don't think this is so hard or uncommon, I just want to show the users his current orders, after he has successfully paid, thats all. I think the user expects a completion and reset once a payment goes through.